# QSerialPort read string

Tags: c++, string, qt, serial-port, signals-slots

So far my application works just fine. But there is one problem. We need to read the data from the serialport. This data may contain only bytes so reading with the readLine() function could give us false or no data. Here is the code now so you can understand my problem.

```
void MainWindow::readData()
{
  while(serial->canReadLine())
  {
       QByteArray data = serial->readLine();

       emit serialPortData(data, false);

       QString myString(data);
       if(myString.startsWith("SensorUpdate"))
       emit sensorData(myString) ;
  }
}
```

I am reading data and if it starts with a string ( some values ) I will send those values to another class where it will update a QTableWidget. But this "startsWith()" only works if I read line by line from the serial port. I want to use the readAll function and maybe store the chars until a new line is found or something like that. Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at Terminal Example you see how to connect up
the readyRead signal and use readall() Normally when you do serial reading. you will read into a buffer (append to it) until u have the expected number of bytes or a "end of transmission" char is seen. like newline. Then a copy of buffer is send to processing and the buffer is cleared and it starts over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to adjust my code. header: `QByteArray charBuffer;` `void MainWindow::readData()
{
    QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
    console->putData(data,false);
    charBuffer.append(data);
    if (data.contains("\n")) //read into a structure until newline received.
    {
        QString myString(charBuffer);            
        if(myString.startsWith("SensorUpdate"))
        emit sensorData(myString);              
        charBuffer = "";                       
    }
}` But it still doesn't work :(

Comment: hi have you checked that input actually do contain "\n" ?
Also which part is not working ? Does it enter
`if (data.contains("\n"))` //read into a structure until newline received.
`{
...

`or not?

Code does look fine :)

Comment: If i get more than one line at each run my gui is not able to handle the data. The readAll function is too fast and gives too much data too handle at a time. I need to handle each line one by one but the readAll function gives me several lines. Soo a solution would be to store the data into a file and read it from there. But maybe there is something else.Thanks @SirajoAbubakaZauro for ur time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you GUI, you could split the QString into a [list](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split) split on \n. Then loop the list and handle each as you normally would. So would not matter if u get more than one in as input.

This is what You had to do.

```
void SensorWidget::fillTable(QString serialString)
{
   tempList = serialString.split("\r\n");

   for(int i=0;i<tempList.size();i++)
   {
       //filll table code
   }
}
```

Comment: Right! I did not check if my Sensorupdate Class got the data so maybe there is the data but my current code was not able to use it! Thank you sooo much!! It finally worked.